# Show a textbox when radiobutton is clicked. How do I do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

We have an online ballot box that presents voters with options for choosing leaders.

Voters can choose any of the listed candidates.

OR they can write a candidate of their choice.

To do so, we woud like to present the voter with a textbox once the checks the Write-In candidate radio button.

How do I do this?

The RadiobuttonList code below is populated dynamically from the database.

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" align="center" style="width:20px;height:20px;zoom:150%; white-space:nowrap;">
</asp:RadioButtonList>

Protected Sub DataList1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles DataList1.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        Dim anstype As HiddenField = e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField1")
        'Dim positionid As Label = e.Item.FindControl("Label3")
        Dim positionid As HiddenField = e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField2")
        Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = e.Item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1")
        Dim cbl As CheckBoxList = e.Item.FindControl("CheckBoxList1")
        Dim txt As TextBox = e.Item.FindControl("TextBox1")
        Dim ds As DataSet = GetDataSet(positionid.Value)
        Select Case anstype.Value
            Case "S"
                rbl.Visible = True
                cbl.Visible = False
                txt.Visible = False
                rbl.DataSource = ds
                rbl.DataTextField = "CandidateName"
                rbl.DataValueField = "CandidateId"
                rbl.DataBind()
            Case "M"
                rbl.Visible = False
                cbl.Visible = True
                txt.Visible = False
                cbl.DataSource = ds
                cbl.DataTextField = "CandidateName"
                cbl.DataValueField = "CandidateId"
                cbl.DataBind()
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

//Code from VIEW SOURCE

```
<tr>
<td><input id="DataList1_RadioButtonList1_5_2_5" type="radio" name="DataList1$ctl06$RadioButtonList1" value="27" /><label for="DataList1_RadioButtonList1_5_2_5">Write In Candidate</label></td>
</tr>
<input name="DataList1$ctl06$writeIn" type="text" id="DataList1_writeIn_5" />


<tr>
<td><input id="DataList1_RadioButtonList1_6_2_6" type="radio" name="DataList1$ctl07$RadioButtonList1" value="28" /><label for="DataList1_RadioButtonList1_6_2_6">Write In Candidate</label></td>
</tr>
<input name="DataList1$ctl07$writeIn" type="text" id="DataList1_writeIn_6" />

<tr>
<td><input id="DataList1_RadioButtonList1_7_1_7" type="radio" name="DataList1$ctl08$RadioButtonList1" value="29" /><label for="DataList1_RadioButtonList1_7_1_7">Write In Candidate</label></td>
</tr>
<input name="DataList1$ctl08$writeIn" type="text" id="DataList1_writeIn_7" />

<tr>
<td><input id="DataList1_RadioButtonList1_8_4_8" type="radio" name="DataList1$ctl09$RadioButtonList1" value="30" /><label for="DataList1_RadioButtonList1_8_4_8">Write In Candidate</label></td>
</tr>
<input name="DataList1$ctl09$writeIn" type="text" id="DataList1_writeIn_8" />

<tr>
<td><input id="DataList1_RadioButtonList1_9_1_9" type="radio" name="DataList1$ctl10$RadioButtonList1" value="31" /><label for="DataList1_RadioButtonList1_9_1_9">Write In Candidate</label></td>
</tr>
<input name="DataList1$ctl10$writeIn" type="text" id="DataList1_writeIn_9" />

<tr>
<td><input id="DataList1_RadioButtonList1_10_1_10" type="radio" name="DataList1$ctl11$RadioButtonList1" value="32" /><label for="DataList1_RadioButtonList1_10_1_10">Write In Candidate</label></td>
</tr>   
 <input name="DataList1$ctl11$writeIn" type="text" id="DataList1_writeIn_10" />
```

Below is screenshot.

[image]

Comment: please share your html markup instead of the server template also where is the text box

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void RadioButtonList1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButton1.Checked)
        {
            //if Radio Button is Checked the Textbox is visible
            TextBox.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (!RadioButton1.Checked)
        {
          //if Radio Button is not Checked the Textbox is In-visible
            TextBox.Visible = false;
        }
     ...
//and show on for other checkbox
```

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw, VB will be great but it doesn't really matter as long as I can convert it. I can't convert Deep's solution though.

Comment: just FYI, `asp.net` is the technology, `vb` and `c#` are languages, describing `asp.net code` alone will be ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this after the code that populates the RadioButtonList.

```
Dim rbWriteIn As New RadioButton()
rbWriteIn.Text = "Write in Candidate"
RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(rbWriteIn)

Dim tbCandidate As New TextBox()
RadioButtonList1Container.Controls.Add(tbCandidate) 'the container of RBL1
tbCandidate.Visible = False

Private Sub showTextBox(ByVal s as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) _
   Handles RadioButtonList1.CheckedChanged
   If rbWriteIn.Checked  Then 
       tbCandidate.Visible = True
   Else
       tbCandidate.Visible = False
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @joker and Gjaa, my apologies. I was unable to test these because my vpn connection died on me and didn't come back till this morning.

I can't get Joker's code to work.

Two problems. One, as you can see from the screenshot, all candidates are selected by checking radio button.

How do I ensure that textbox display only when write In Candidate box is checked?

Also, I tried making it hiddden on pageload but I keep null exception error.

Comment: your code is promising with the IF statement but the write is for president, vice president and secretary. There are seven people contesting for secretary position.

That's why this task is tough

Comment: I really appreciate the help. I have updated my original code above with two sets of codes (sorry for many codes).

The first shows how radio buttons are created. Each name on the db with a value of S means Radio button.

Then the second code shows the actual values for both radio button and textbox.

What I would like is that if radiobutton value is 27 like above, make textbox with id of `DataList1_writeIn_5`. Same with the rest. Can you help integrate your code with that?

Comment: I'm unable to help you any further, sorry, I've got desktop backgrounds. Maybe you need a little JavaScript, it's a dynamic behaviour that you want to get.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/86493/how-to-make-controls-visible-false-using-JavaScript) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx) msnd tutorial can help you

Comment: I understand. This is by no means a simple solution.

So, thanks a lot for your efforts.